# "И" — частица или союз?

Tags: части-речи, и

*Оно* [счастье] *приходит туда, где человек настроен на постижение главной, и по сути единственной мечты человечества: жить человеком, быть человеком, любить человеком. **И** мечтать только об этом.*

Во втором предложении "и" является частицей или союзом? Почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Жуть. Должно быть как-то так:

Счастье приходит к тому, кто настроен на достижение главной и, по сути, единственной цели человечества: быть человеком, жить и любить по-человечески. И мечтает только об этом.

*И* - союз, так как соединяет однородные члены, разорванные в результате парцелляции (деления предложения на два с помощью точки). В исходном варианте И соединяет "любить" и "мечтать", в предложенном - "настроен" и "мечтает".

Можно также сказать, что И присоединяет парцеллированное предложение.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что это все-таки союз. Союз – служебная часть речи, которая связывает однородные члены, простые предложения в составе сложного, а также предложения в тексте. 
 [Сочинительные союзы](http://www.virtualacademy.ru/repetitory/po-russkomu-yazyku/) — это союзы, которые служат для связи
однородных членов предложения и равноправных по смыслу
простых предложений в составе сложного:

> Бывало, с самого раннего утра убегаю или на пруд, или в рощу, или на сенокос.  Наступила ночь, и пошёл снег.

Answer (score -1):

мне кажется, что тут это все-таки частица. ее можно свободно выкинуть, и смысл вообще не изменится